# Libgit2sharp get list of items from remote branch

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I am trying to retrieve the list of items(if there are any) from a remote branch using libgit2sharp.

currently, I am pushing my local branch to the remote repository and I want to add a check whether there are items in that branch already.

I am trying to disallow the user to upload his local folder into the remote repository if there are files other than the README in the remote branch which the user tries to push into.

is it possible?

Comment: Suppose there is only the README file in the remote branch. A user can then push a different file one time only? After that no one can ever push anything anymore? (I assume that isn't what you intended the logic to be?)

Comment: You can keep pushing files, new and update current files as long as it doesn’t conflict with the files in the remote. The logic around it is that the user won’t push to a repository which already contain files( just trying to protect the user from using it the wrong way)

Comment: The way I read your comment, those two sentences conflict with each other. Suppose I push a file named `file1`. Now I can't push again or update that file because the branch now has a file in it that isn't the README file.

Comment: I'll elaborate more, thanks for notifying me that my question wasn't clear enough.
I am uploading a local project into a repository in Github/Gitlab using libgit2sharp.
I don't want the user to upload the project into a repository which contains files that aren't relevant for the project itself, so that's why I am trying to first check if there are any files other than the README in the repository as the user should upload his project into a clean repository which will contain only the projects files and the README if there is any

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't matter if I understand the logic. ;) For listing files in git from the command line you can use `git ls-tree -r branch-name`.  I don't see the recursive (`-r`) option in the [libgit2sharp documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-ls-tree) but from your problem description you may not need it anyway.